# infinite scroll in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
            ng-if="canWeLoadMoreContent()"
            on-infinite="getOrderHistory()" 
            distance="2%">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

ion-infinite-scroll calls `canWeLoadMoreContent()` only the first time page is loaded and I can go on with that.

However, I need `ion-infinite-scroll` to call `canWeLoadMoreContent()` as soon as the state is loaded. It calls the function only first time and then on further scrolls.

For `canWeLoadMoreContent()` to be called again, I need to refresh it in browser which ofcourse can not work in android browsers.

How do I reinitialize `infinite scroll` every time?

Comment: Here is a working example http://codepen.io/elm/pen/Becqp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');` in your `getOrderHistory()` method.

You can check the example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/elm/pen/Becqp).